# Dismiss ionic 2 modal from typescript component

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, modal-dialog, hybrid

I have created a modal using modalController in ionic 2.

`import { ModalController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';`
The issue is it can be only be dismissed either from backdrop or from inside the modal contoller like

`this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);`

I want to programmitially dismiss the modal from the component on which its being used.

Comment: For these cases we have used a shared service, to which you can call methods to open and close modal/alert etc.

Comment: @Alex , can you help how have you implemented that service , I mean how its dismissing the modal

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shared service, where you have methods to open and close a modal. Then just call those methods from the component you like. For example service:

```ts
modal: any;

constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) { }

createModal() {
  this.modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalComponent);
  this.modal.present();
}

closeModal() {
  this.modal.dismiss();
}
```

Then just inject this service to the component of your choosing and call the methods.

Here's a sample, the modal is instantly opened, and after 3 seconds closed:

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8onx4s?file=app%2Fservice.ts)